Make all constructor attributes optional in PHP
I would like to know if I can use Partial like typescript.
For instance I have this class:
class Registration {
    public function __construct(
        public readonly int $year,
        public readonly int $coverage,
        public readonly string $start_date,
        public readonly string $state_address,
    ) {
    }
}

Is there a way to create a class from the original, with those rules:

Don't modify the original class.
Don't create a constructor in the child class.
Make all properties partial.

It there like a magic function in PHP that can do it? Something like this:
class RegitrationPartial extends Partial(Registration) { }

Now I can call that class in this way:
new RegitrationPartial(year: 2025);


You can use something called named arguments, this allows you to specify the exact argument you want to populate. Your actually pretty close already.
<?php

class Registration {
    public function __construct(
        public readonly ?int $year = null,
        public readonly ?int $coverage = null,
        public readonly ?string $start_date = null,
        public readonly ?string $state_address = null,
    ) {
        //
    }
}

$Registration = new Registration(year: 2025);

Some further reading on named arguments
https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-named-arguments

Hi @LewBlu , thank you. I updated the question. The idea is not modify the original class. It must be required always. The idea is create a new one from the original, but all parameters partial, like typescript Partial utility.

There are two obvious errors in this code: 1. Properties of int or string type cannot be null. 2. The new operatior is missing.

Also, OP specifically stated they do not want to modify the original.

@AlbertTjornejoj No worries, I get what you mean now that you have updated the question (the "convert" through me off). Wasn't aware you were unable to modify the original class. Henro-sutrisno-tanjung's will be more appropriate in that scenario.

You can create a RegistrationPartial class that extends the original class and uses optional parameters in its constructor, providing null as default values. after that, you can send those optional parameters to the parent class based on whether they are provided or not.
this one should work:
class Registration {
    public function __construct(
        public readonly int $year,
        public readonly int $coverage,
        public readonly string $start_date,
        public readonly string $state_address
    ) { }
}

class RegistrationPartial extends Registration {
    public function __construct(
        ?int $year = null,
        ?int $coverage = null,
        ?string $start_date = null,
        ?string $state_address = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $year ?? 0, // Provide default or placeholder value
            $coverage ?? 0,
            $start_date ?? '',
            $state_address ?? ''
        );
    }
}

// Usage:
$partial = new RegistrationPartial(year: 2025);


I know I can do it. But if you class has a lot of properties, we need to replicate it many times. Also if you want to apply it to many classes, you need to replicate the same ideas many times. I was asking something like Partial Typescript utility. If exists some magic functions in PHP similar that do the same that Typescript.
